# Invalid token and Invalid syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a question in python's error case. I have tried here....

```
>>> 0o08
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> 0o8
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

I want to know:

- Which is the invalid token, `0`, `o` or `8`?
- Why is `0o08` invalid syntax?

Comment: Because 'o' is not a number. What number do you expect 0o8 to be?

Comment: By the way, in octal the value (decimal) `8` is `0o10`

Comment: I have tried to tidy up your question; does that still correspond with what you want to know?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An integer literal starting with `0o` is interpreted as [**octal**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal). Per [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#integer-literals):

```
octinteger     ::=  "0" ("o" | "O") octdigit+  # '0o' or '0O' followed by one or more...
... 
octdigit       ::=  "0"..."7"                  # ...digits 0 to 7 inclusive
```

The token `8` is not a valid `octdigit`, so is not allowed in an octal literal, hence *"invalid token"*.

---

The reason that the error messages are different is that (related to Python's LL(1) parser, which only looks ahead one token at a time):

- If the *first token* after `0o` is not an `octdigit`, that is clearly an invalid token and parsing stops immediately; whereas
- If *subsequent tokens* happen to be invalid, this isn't detected at such an early stage and parsing continues until the whole line gets rejected as invalid syntax.

You can see this difference in the highlighting in IDLE (only `0o` highlighted vs. whole line highlighted), and if you try some alternatives:

```
>>> 0ok  # first token is invalid
SyntaxError: invalid token
>>> 0o18  # subsequent token is invalid
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> 0o10  # all tokens are valid
8
```

Comment: @BankComSci out of interest: was it just the first bit (`8` isn't a valid octal digit) you wanted, or the second bit (why the messages differ for two invalid literals) as well?

Comment: I have a last question. 02492  >>> invalid token so which is the invalid token? Why not invalid syntax?

Comment: @BankComSci `2` in Python 3.x, which requires the token after a leading `0` to be either `o` or `O`; `0o2492` would give *"invalid syntax"*. `9` in Python 2.x, because a leading `0` (with or without `o`/`O`) means octal.